# Regular expression and repeating character classes in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression that can extract (possibly multiple) strings of four hexadecimal numbers/letters.

I could do something like this:
`/^[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]/`

but is there a better way?

It seems like the repeat operator:

> a{n} Matches 'a' repeated exactly n times.
>
> a{n,} Matches 'a' repeated n or more times.
>
> a{n, m} Matches 'a' repeated between n and m times inclusive.

Would work, but the following regular expression does not seem to work:

```
/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}+/
```

I'm trying to match strings like:

AA00

AA00FFAA

0011FFAA0022

and so on.  Each string will be on it's own line.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also say `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `[A-Fa-f0-9]`.  It conveys the intent more clearly IMHO.

Comment: @Sean: `\p{ahex}` is infinitely better: the `[[:posix:]]` noise is just that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})+$/
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfect.  Would you care to explain how exactly this works?   I understand that the () creates a group accessed by $1.. $2 ect, but how does the ?: come into play?  The reference page I usually access for these things explains it like this: "(?:regex):  Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex operators, but do not capture anything and do not create backreferences."

Comment: Exactly.  Since you can use the whole value of the match, you don't need to have the extra expense of capturing the stuff inside the parenthasis.  It's just a simple optimization.  So because of the `(?:)`, you won't get a value in match.Groups[1].  That's the only difference.

Comment: Furthermore......   What happens if I need to support a series of fixed characters between the hex numbers..   Say \z is a separator, eg \zaa00\zffff\z0101 ?   I attempted to modify your regular expression but I'm still working on understanding it.  Thanks a bunch for your extremely helpful responses!

Comment: Add `(?:\\z|$)` so it will either match `\z` or `$` (end of string).  I think it's like this, but I can never remember how to escape slashes in perl.  `/^(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}(?:\\\\z|$))+$/`

Comment: when slashes are part of the thing I'm trying to match, i usually use `m:/stuf/:` instead of `m/\/stuf\//`.

Comment: I see a problem with this solution. String "Ab82" will also match. I think a check for the equality of two characters should be added.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested quantifiers in regex; ie, {4} means to match **exactly 4 times** and **+** means to match that string many times, so these two quantifiers conflict. If you simply remove the **+**, it'll work:

```
/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}/
```

Comment: Except for the `^`, which matches the beginning of the string.

Comment: He also wants to match AA00FFAA and 0011FFAA0022. i.e. Any sequence of length `4N`

Comment: I don't see the problem with that? The question has the `^` in there as well, and all the example strings start with the match.

Comment: it will only match exactly the first 4 characters of the line.  You need to match multiples of 4 starting at the beginning of the line.

Comment: `/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}/` will also match six hex characters, which he doesn't want to match. e.g. `AA00FF`